# google youtube data api list videos - limit to total items returned

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am doing a search for videos using the keyword "woodturning". I have MaxResults set to 50, and use the returned NextPageToken to request more videos. On the 10th request, NextPageToken is null. So I can only get 500 items returned.

If I do a similar search from the youtube web page, I see a figure of more than 47,000 videos.

How do I get around this 500 item return limit?

Comment: BTW, I'm using v3 of the data api.

Answer (score 1):

After more searching, I found the answer already on stackexchange. Youtube is imposing a 500 item limit on search results.